# How can I generate *.mflow?

Tags: maven, mule, mule-studio, mflow

I have Mule project. I read [here](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Preparing+a+gitignore+File) what folder `flows`
 and file `*.mflow` should be ignored. I deleted `*.mflow` from repository. But I don't know how I can generate it now. I read about [maven-mule-plugin](https://github.com/mulesoft/maven-mule-plugin), but is it possible to generate `*.mflow` using this plugin? What command do I need for this?

So how can I get `*.mflow` using mainflow.xml?

Comment: It is necessary to add `<natures>... <nature>org.mule.tooling.core.muleNature</nature> </natures>` in `.project` and open mainflow.xml in Mule Studio.

Answer (score 1):

mflow files are not being used nor generated anymore in latests Studio versions, please download one of the latests versions and have fun using only the mule-config.xml. Here you can find the release notes where you can find this information: http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Anypoint+Studio+October+2014+Release+Notes

Comment: also they were useless, just interim data from the IDE to be able to render and modify the actual .xml.